# How to Import Materialize.scss with ES6 / Webpack?

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, materialize

I have this but it fails.

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../node_modules/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="card-panel teal lighten-2">
        <h1> fad </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Say's Module parse `failed \fonts\roboto\roboto-bold.woff2 unexpected character ' ' (1:4)`

my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: "./app/index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./app",
    inline: true,
    port: 3333
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style!css"
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss/,
        loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Edit

SVG is not working

```
ERROR in ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3
Module parse failed:node_modules\font-awesome\fonts\fonta
esome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3 Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

also I just noticed ttf and woff2 does not work as well

```
ERROR in ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3
Module parse failed:node_modules\font-awesome\fonts\fontaw
esome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3 Unexpected character ' ' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

My Loader

```
{
         test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff2?|otf|svg)$/,
    loaders: ['file']
      }
```

I did fine this will work

```
 {
        test: /\.woff($|\?)|\.woff2($|\?)|\.ttf($|\?)|\.eot($|\?)|\.svg($|\?)/,
        loader: 'url-loader'
      }
```

but it is using url-loader not file-loader not sure what the difference is between the 2 loaders.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you still need a separate loader for the font files.

Install `file-loader` and add this to your webpack.config.js:

```
{
    test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff2?|otf)$/,
    loaders: ['file']
}
```

Comment: That worked but now I ran into the issue with font-awesome .svg files. I tried to add 'svg' to the test list but it still did not like the svg files.

Comment: Hmm, adding it should work. What error did you receive?

Comment: See my edit. I got it working with url-loader but not file-loader